# User upload content

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I wanted to crate an mobile app (using Flex) that let user upload some user generated content (eg. Text, Picture) to my website and also able to display/view it on the website as well.

I don’t much on the back end (web programming, website database, cloud).

What is the best way to do this or is there any ready build solution out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at httpService for your user upload and tie it to a back end web service using POST or GET parameters. Personally, I recommend PHP but any web capable service would work. Then, tie that service to store your images on your web server or in a database. Reverse the process to get it back out. Can this all be done in Flex? No. Can you tie it in with a web service easily? Yes.  Good luck.

Comment: thank, guest Flex is quit limited to client side only.